# BSD hard disk designation

Tags: arrays, hard-drive, bsd

I have a hard disk array which runs on an OS based on BSD. I want to acces some hard disk information on it directly but I cant seem to figure out what the hard drives are. In linux it would /dev/sda,/dev/sdb etc.

here is an output from a ls in /dev

```
MAKEDEV         ipcdev21        lv3             rpd12d          rsd0a
MAKEDEV.local   ipcdev22        lv4             rpd13d          rsd0b
bat             ipcdev23        lv5             rpd14d          rsd0c
bpf0            ipcdev24        lv6             rpd15d          rsd0d
bpf1            ipcdev25        lv7             rpd16d          rsd0e
bpf2            ipcdev26        lv8             rpd17d          rsd0f
bptemp0         ipcdev27        lv9             rpd18d          rsd0g
bptemp1         ipcdev28        mem             rpd19d          rsd0h
class           ipcdev29        null            rpd1d           rsf0d
cmtemp0         ipcdev3         ptyp0           rpd20d          sbprof
console         ipcdev30        ptyp1           rpd21d          sbqrqprof
cord            ipcdev31        ptyp2           rpd22d          sd0a
cputemp0        ipcdev32        ptyp3           rpd23d          sd0b
drum            ipcdev33        ptyp4           rpd24d          sd0c
dty00           ipcdev34        ptyp5           rpd25d          sd0d
dty01           ipcdev35        ptyp6           rpd26d          sd0e
ecd             ipcdev36        ptyp7           rpd27d          sd0f
ecd1            ipcdev37        ptyp8           rpd28d          sd0g
emm             ipcdev38        ptyp9           rpd29d          sd0h
eql_bp_eeprom   ipcdev39        ptypA           rpd2d           ses0
eql_cm_eeprom   ipcdev4         ptypB           rpd30d          sf0d
eql_dc_eeprom   ipcdev40        ptypC           rpd31d          stderr
eql_emm0_eeprom ipcdev41        ptypD           rpd32d          stdin
eql_emm1_eeprom ipcdev42        ptypE           rpd33d          stdout
eqlcache        ipcdev43        ptypF           rpd34d          tty
eqlcache_chr    ipcdev44        ptypG           rpd35d          tty00
eqlcache_data   ipcdev45        ptypH           rpd36d          tty01
eqlcache_r0     ipcdev46        ptypI           rpd37d          ttyp0
eqlcache_r1     ipcdev47        ptypJ           rpd38d          ttyp1
eqlcache_r2     ipcdev48        ptypK           rpd39d          ttyp2
eqlcache_r3     ipcdev49        ptypL           rpd3d           ttyp3
eqlfw           ipcdev5         ptypM           rpd40d          ttyp4
eqliom          ipcdev50        ptypN           rpd41d          ttyp5
eqliomlv0       ipcdev51        ptypO           rpd42d          ttyp6
eqliomlv0a      ipcdev52        ptypP           rpd43d          ttyp7
eqliomlv1       ipcdev53        ptypQ           rpd44d          ttyp8
eqliomlv2       ipcdev54        ptypR           rpd45d          ttyp9
eqliomlv3       ipcdev55        ptypS           rpd46d          ttypA
eqliomlv4       ipcdev56        ptypT           rpd47d          ttypB
eqliomlv5       ipcdev57        ptypU           rpd48d          ttypC
eqllogQ         ipcdev58        ptypV           rpd49d          ttypD
eqllogQdump     ipcdev59        ptypW           rpd4d           ttypE
eqllogQread     ipcdev6         ptypX           rpd50d          ttypF
eqlraid_chr_0a  ipcdev60        ptypY           rpd51d          ttypG
eqlraid_chr_1a  ipcdev61        ptypZ           rpd52d          ttypH
eqlraid_chr_2a  ipcdev62        ptypa           rpd53d          ttypI
eqlraid_chr_3a  ipcdev63        ptypb           rpd54d          ttypJ
eqlraid_chr_4a  ipcdev64        ptypc           rpd55d          ttypK
eqlraid_chr_5a  ipcdev65        ptypd           rpd56d          ttypL
eqlraid_chr_6a  ipcdev66        ptype           rpd57d          ttypM
eqlraid_chr_7a  ipcdev67        ptypf           rpd58d          ttypN
eqlraid_chr_8a  ipcdev68        ptypg           rpd59d          ttypO
eqlraid_chr_9a  ipcdev69        ptyph           rpd5d           ttypP
eqlraid_mgr     ipcdev7         ptypi           rpd60d          ttypQ
fs              ipcdev70        ptypj           rpd61d          ttypR
ipcdev0         ipcdev71        ptypk           rpd62d          ttypS
ipcdev1         ipcdev72        ptypl           rpd63d          ttypT
ipcdev10        ipcdev73        ptypm           rpd64d          ttypU
ipcdev100       ipcdev74        ptypn           rpd65d          ttypV
ipcdev101       ipcdev75        ptypo           rpd66d          ttypW
ipcdev102       ipcdev76        ptypp           rpd67d          ttypX
ipcdev103       ipcdev77        ptypq           rpd68d          ttypY
ipcdev104       ipcdev78        ptypr           rpd69d          ttypZ
ipcdev105       ipcdev79        ptyps           rpd6d           ttypa
ipcdev106       ipcdev8         ptypt           rpd70d          ttypb
ipcdev107       ipcdev80        ptypu           rpd71d          ttypc
ipcdev108       ipcdev81        ptypv           rpd72d          ttypd
ipcdev109       ipcdev82        ptypw           rpd73d          ttype
ipcdev11        ipcdev83        ptypx           rpd74d          ttypf
ipcdev110       ipcdev84        ptypy           rpd75d          ttypg
ipcdev111       ipcdev85        ptypz           rpd76d          ttyph
ipcdev112       ipcdev86        random          rpd77d          ttypi
ipcdev113       ipcdev87        reqlfw          rpd78d          ttypj
ipcdev114       ipcdev88        reqliomlv0a     rpd79d          ttypk
ipcdev115       ipcdev89        rpd0d           rpd7d           ttypl
ipcdev116       ipcdev9         rpd100d         rpd80d          ttypm
ipcdev117       ipcdev90        rpd101d         rpd81d          ttypn
ipcdev118       ipcdev91        rpd102d         rpd82d          ttypo
ipcdev119       ipcdev92        rpd103d         rpd83d          ttypp
ipcdev12        ipcdev93        rpd104d         rpd84d          ttypq
ipcdev120       ipcdev94        rpd105d         rpd85d          ttypr
ipcdev121       ipcdev95        rpd106d         rpd86d          ttyps
ipcdev122       ipcdev96        rpd107d         rpd87d          ttypt
ipcdev123       ipcdev97        rpd108d         rpd88d          ttypu
ipcdev124       ipcdev98        rpd109d         rpd89d          ttypv
ipcdev125       ipcdev99        rpd10d          rpd8d           ttypw
ipcdev126       klog            rpd110d         rpd90d          ttypx
ipcdev127       kmem            rpd111d         rpd91d          ttypy
ipcdev13        lv0             rpd112d         rpd92d          ttypz
ipcdev14        lv1             rpd113d         rpd93d          urandom
ipcdev15        lv10            rpd114d         rpd94d          uuid
ipcdev16        lv11            rpd115d         rpd95d          vsc0
ipcdev17        lv12            rpd116d         rpd96d          vsc1
ipcdev18        lv13            rpd117d         rpd97d          vsc_sys
ipcdev19        lv14            rpd118d         rpd98d          wdog
ipcdev2         lv15            rpd119d         rpd99d          zero
ipcdev20        lv2             rpd11d          rpd9d
```

Answer (score 1):

The whole disc is `/dev/rsd0c` (character device), and the slices (BSD disklabel partitions) are `/dev/sd0a` until `/dev/sd0h`. The `/dev/sd0c` slice is the whole disc again (block device).

Commonly, `/dev/sd0b` is swap, and `/dev/sd0a` would contain the root filesystem.

In older FreeBSD® variants and some ports of NetBSD®, `/dev/sd0d` refers to the whole disc, and `/dev/sd0c` would instead refer to the whole MBR partition containing the BSD disklabel.

You can use the `mount` command to check what filesystems are currently mounted from where, and `disklabel sd0` (as root) to inspect the BSD disklabel (or `disklabel /dev/rsd0c` or `disklabel /dev/rsd0d`, depending on the OS in question).